# Pandas: How to do operations using loc with multiple columns and format the results

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

[Here](https://github.com/veekun/pokedex/blob/master/pokedex/data/csv/abilities.csv) is the csv file I using.

Goals:

1. I want to extract the rows that has values of columns "generation_id" or "is_main_series" greater than 0 and assign them a variable "selection"
   (Just to be clear, I want rows that has at least one of two columns greater than 0.)
2. Then, I extract the "identifier" columns from the "selection" and assign them a variable "name".
3. Finally, I would like to format the rows of "selection" for each "name" in this way --> name(generation_id, is_main_series), name1(is_main_series), etc

Error:
line 7: ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

I'm struggling to find solution for this error because I don't think this Dataframe is multiindexed.

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('abilities.csv')
df = df.fillna(0)

def getPokedex():
    selection = df.loc[df[['generation_id', 'is_main_series']] != 0 ]
    for donor in selection:
        name = selection['identifier']
        name = name.to_string(index=False)
        for types in selection.columns:
            return f"{name}(types)"

print(getPokedex())
```

Would appreciate any help.

**UPDATED:**
Excel File sample:

```
TypeA1, TypeA2, TypeA3, TypeA4, TypeA5, TypeA6, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD, TypeE
20, 0, 10, 4, 0.5, 75, 1000, 0, 2, 14
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 23, 2, 10, 34
```

Code I wrote:

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
    
    df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsm', header=2)
    # Replace empty cells with 0
    df = df.fillna(0)
    
    # Format rows
    df['Formatted_column'] = df['Name'] + '(' + np.where(df[['TypeA1', 'TypeA2', 'TypeA3', 'TypeA4', 'TypeA5', 'TypeA6']].astype(str) !='0', 'A', '') + ',' + np.where(df['TypeB'].astype(str) !='0', 'B', '') + np.where(df['TypeC'].astype(str) !='0', 'C', '') + np.where(df['TypeD'].astype(str) !='0', 'D', '') + np.where(df['E'].astype(str) !='0', 'E', '') + ')'
    print(', '.join(df['Formatted_column'].to_list()))
```

My desired outcome would be james(A,C), mary(C), luke(A,B,D), etc

But Python raises this error in line 8:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Sample exact output of what you want would be helpful

Comment: e.g. stench(generation_id, is_main_series), drizzle(generation_id, is_main_series), sandpit(generation_id)
So I want for a name/identifier to display a column names either generation_id or is_main_series (not id) that are not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you. I think I can resolve the first at least. You are comparing a list with a number. It doesn't look fine. Did you try something like this?:

```py
// get the boolean values
booleanValues = (df.iloc[:,2] != 0) | (df.iloc[:,3] != 0)
// then get the df filtered
df_filtered = df[booleanValues]
```

I think the error raised is that. Then I have to think about the remainder of the code but I wanted to give you this quick help.

Comment: Never mind. I got it working using your code. Thank you for your help. Would appreciate very much if you helped me to solve the other two problems I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to print rows in a particular format, for which "generation_id" or "is_main_series" greater than 0. You can try the below code. See comments inline

```
import pandas as pd    
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/veekun/pokedex/master/pokedex/data/csv/abilities.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(url)

#Filter dataframe for generation_id or is_main_series greater than 0
df = df[(df['generation_id']>0) | (df['is_main_series']>0)]

#Format and print the rows.
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['identifier'],'(', row['generation_id'], ',' , row['is_main_series'] ,')')
```

**Output:**

```
stench ( 3 , 1 )
drizzle ( 3 , 1 )
speed-boost ( 3 , 1 )
battle-armor ( 3 , 1 )
...
shackle ( 5 , 0 )
decoy ( 5 , 0 )
shield ( 5 , 0 )
```

**Or**

If you want the output of all columns in one line with comma separated, you can do this. Here the idea is to create a new column which you need  to print it later. And then convert the column to list and then join it as a comma separated string.

```
df['Formatted_column'] = df['identifier'] + '(' + np.where(df['generation_id'].astype(str) !='0', 'generation_id', '') + ',' + np.where(df['is_main_series'].astype(str) !='0', 'is_main_series', '') +')'
print(', '.join(df['Formatted_column'].to_list()))
```

**Output of this**

```
stench(generation_id,is_main_series), drizzle(generation_id,is_main_series), speed-boost(generation_id,is_main_series),  .... shackle(generation_id,), decoy(generation_id,), shield(generation_id,)
```

Comment: thank you for your insight. just one thing, I want the column headers to display within the parenthesis, not the value itself.

Comment: question: is .astype(str) removing indexes and dtypes and stuff?

Comment: to continue for my first comment, I do not wish to display a header value which its value is zero. So e.g. if shackle has 5 for generation_id and 0 for is_main_series the formatted version would be shackle(generation_id)

Comment: @KevinMorlock: I have updated the answer. Please check the second part of the answer. Using numpy where, we can check and replace the string.

Comment: I tried this code with my excel file that has three headers and I require just the third one to work with the file, and it gives me an error. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Question is completely changed now. You are now reading a different file altogether

Comment: Sorry, but I wanted to work with both files and thought it will work. Is the answer different? If you can, could you please provide me with a code that can work on my excel file?